# Add external file to Spring boot class path resource

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a file (not a part of packaged jar) that needs to be in classpath so that Spring boot can find and load the file as a part of other resources.

PS: this file is not a Spring Boot application properties file.

Answer (score -1):

Either

1. Edit the classpath when you run the JAR
2. Distribute the file with the JAR and read as if it were any other file on the filesystem, perhaps using CLI arguments to provide a reference